# i need the full dom node path of element

Tags: dom

i need to search the html document for `<p class="content"> text here </p>`

and then output the full node path (CSS or XPATH)

for isntance

```
html > body > div class ="something" > table > tr > p class="content"
```

i tried with nokogiri but it doesn't handle the class and other attributes well..

i need a parser that does this without problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok try this:

```
var path = [];

var el = document.getElementById('myNode');

do {
    path.unshift(el.nodeName + (el.className ? ' class="' + el.className + '"' : ''));
} while ((el.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'html') && (el = el.parentNode));

alert(path.join(" > "));
```

Comment: how about if the element doesnt have a id. (i didnt write the page, i get to process it after render) ?

Comment: use whatever method you have to get a reference to that element - `getElementByTagName`, or jQuery or whatever.