# What is the path in the html dom for a selected element?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, path

I am trying to get the path in the html dom for a specific object.
Using javascript or jquery.(When I select/hover over the object.)

I do not know the structure in advance.

For example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                Not selected
            </div>
            <div>
                Selected Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "Selected Text" Div path should be something like:

```
//HTML/BODY/DIV[0]/DIV[1]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484875/i-need-the-full-dom-node-path-of-element) but it does not give an indication regarding the index of the element (In my example the value in the square brackets - 1 in `DIV[1]`).

By the way is there a "technical" name for this path?
I have seen the term XPath but am not sure that this is it.

Be happy and enjoy life.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following function does what you want, using jQuery:

```
function getElementPath(element)
{
    return "//" + $(element).parents().andSelf().map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tagName = this.nodeName;
        if ($this.siblings(tagName).length > 0) {
            tagName += "[" + $this.prevAll(tagName).length + "]";
        }
        return tagName;
    }).get().join("/").toUpperCase();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        window.alert(getElementPath(this));
    });
});
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ygqcW/93/).

Comment: @Julian, you're welcome :) I just realized that it won't add a `[0]` index to elements that don't have siblings, although your example does, but I guess that can be considered as a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: @Fredeeic Hamidi - That's an excellent feature ;-)

Comment: cool, my search ended here, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$("html > div")[0].find("div")[1`]

**XPath is not available in Jquery anymore.**

If you need Xpath, just use Firebug under FF, or Chrome.

Concerning having anyelemtn being selected(option) :

```
$("option:selected")
```

To get a div being hover :

```
$("div:hover")
```

or a checkbox :

```
$("checkbox:selected")
```

Now let's take an example:

```
<div>
   <div class='again'>
      <select id='select1'>
         <option val='1'>
         <option val='2'>
      </select>


      <select id='select2'>
         <option val='1'>
         <option val='2'>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now how to get the first list being selected :

```
$("#select2 > option:selected")
```

or

```
$('.again >select')[0].find("option:selected")
```

getting the div being hovered :

```
('.secondDIv').hover(function(){
},function(){});
```

etc etc

Comment: @user544287 I am not sure that you understood my question. I am trying to get the path of any element that is selected/hovered not only the example that I gave.